# jquery data set cannot change value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have problem when using data selector. I cannot change value of data-selector, is there something wrong with my code?

this initial data.
[image: this]

I have changed the value but why are the results still the same? Try to see the progress bar, the progress bar should be full if the value is 100.

[image]

this my ajax

```
$('#btn_update').on('click',function(){
            resetState(xd, dataArr, 'reset');
            var gdgtyp = $("input[name='gdgtype']:checked").val();
            var lantaiid=$('#lantaiid').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?= base_url('ajxsrama');?>",
                data: { gdgtyp: gdgtyp, lantaiid: lantaiid}, 
                cache: false,
                success: function(result) {
                    lantai.textContent = JSON.parse(result).lantaix;
                    tipe.textContent = JSON.parse(result).tipex;
                    dataArr = JSON.parse(result).alldata;
                    console.log(JSON.parse(result).tersedia);
                    console.log($('#progtersedia .progress-number').text(JSON.parse(result).tersedia));
                    console.log($('#progtersedia').data('percent',JSON.parse(result).tersedia));
                    console.log($('#progtersedia').data());
                    dtbooking = JSON.parse(result).booking;
                    dtterisi = JSON.parse(result).terisi;
                    dtrusak = JSON.parse(result).rusak;

                    resetState(xd, dataArr, 'success_call');
                }
            });
        });
```

this is for bar

```
<div class="p-progress-bar-container radius small title-up">
<div  class="p-progress-bar" data-percent="<?= $box['tersedia'];?>" data-delay="100" data-type="%"  id="progtersedia">
    <div class="progress-title" >Kosong</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think css could handle the data, then you use the width element. You can use the `attr` selector to handle css, and then you need to give `width = yourpercent` , so for your code it will be : `$('#progtersedia').attr('style','width : ' + JSON.parse(result).tersedia+'%');`